# Transfer WhatsApp messages from iOS to Android

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-transfer, ios, device-migration

I want to move my WhatsApp messages from my iPhone 5c to my OnePlus Nord N200 5G running Android 12. I've been running WhatsApp in an iPhone 5c with iOS, which is the last iOS version for this iPhone. Recently WhatsApp forced users to upgrade to the latest iOS app, but the latest version is only supported for iOS 12+. I am now locked out of WhatsApp.

Before I was locked out, I followed the official steps [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/625237248445474) multiple times to perform this migration, but the messages are never transferred to Android. Under "How to migrate from iPhone to Android 12 and above", after substep 5, I am never prompted to scan a QR code and open WhatsApp iOS; I get no Whatsapp-related notification on Android. I don't get an error message. I tried the transfer both during the initial setup phase after the factory reset and after you get a notification asking you to finish setting up your phone.

There's an app called MobileTrans that claims to transfer WhatsApp messages between the two platforms, but it's not free, and I've heard your data is transferred to a third party.

Comment: What was the last step from the linked migration guide you were able to perform successfully?

Comment: I updated the question. Under "How to migrate from iPhone to Android 12 and above," substep 5.

Comment: Possible dupe: [How to move WhatsApp chat history from iPhone to Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140618/44325)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move WhatsApp chat history from iPhone to Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42357/how-to-move-whatsapp-chat-history-from-iphone-to-android)

Comment: I'm mentioned in my question I don't want to use MobileTrans, etc., because I'm concerned whether they transfer your data to a third party. I've tried all those answers except [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/44323/251629), which I have doubts will work because its 9 years old and iOS is locked down. But I've moved on from this issue.